# Circular progress bar in Unity 3D - UnityScript

Tags: unity-game-engine, progress-bar, geometry, unityscript

I want to make a circular progress-bar for my video game in UnityScript. How can I achieve that by using a 3d model/texture for it? I haven't written any code yet and this is just a question on how to do something like this in plain UnityScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alpha gradient texture that is then used as a cutoff for your progress bar image.

Note that you'll need to use shaders for this to work and set the _cutoff variable for this by hand.

Another approach would be to use the [NGUI](http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) plugin and use an UISprite with radial fill, that's gonna do the same thing but without the need to modify the shader params by hand. On the down side the NGUI plugin is not free.

Comment: So you suggest I make an normal circle and then use a smaller one inside it to cut the inner part and make it circular? I can't quite understand what you mean when you say that I can use an "alpha gradient"

Comment: No, I'm suggesting making an image the same size as your circle that's black apart from the circle itself. The circle is made of shades of white that go from 255 to 0 according to the path you want the progress bar to take. 

You use both of this images with the Unlit/Transparent Cutout shader that only renders pixels that have corresponding white values in the   alpha texture above a certain value. This is the _cutoff param.There's a tutorial about how to do this here http://www.twistedshield.com/wordpress/?p=234 but the alpha gradient is used to show the progress bar go from top to bottom.